# Warum heißt der Außenleiter (Dreh-/Wechselstrom) so, wie er heißt?

Tags: etymology, technical-terminology

Warum heißt der Außenleiter (Dreh-/Wechselstrom) so, wie er heißt?

Meine Idee wäre, dass es so ist, weil der Nullleiter in einer Stern- und Dreiecksschaltung in der Mitte ist und die anderen Leiter halt außen sind.

Comment: Ist das nicht auch der, der unter Spannung steht (und so diese nach außen leitet)? Ich finde deine Erklärung aber auch einigermaßen plausibel..

Comment: Meine Theorie würde untersützt werden dadurch, dass der Neutralleiter auch Rückleiter genannt wird..

Comment: Hab gerade nochmal meinen "die Spannung leitet"-Kommentar gelesen. Bin zusammengezuckt ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Außenleiter ([nach DIN VDE 0100, Teil 200](http://www.iv-krause.de/media/pdf/Kataloge/AmprobeBeha/Wissenswertes))

> Außenleiter sind Leiter, die Stromquellen mit Verbrauchsmitteln verbinden, aber nicht vom Mittel- oder Sternpunkt ausgehen

oder [verständlicher](https://www.baunetzwissen.de/glossar/a/aussenleiter-3425437)

> Als Außenleiter bezeichnet man die Leiter in einem Drehstromkreis, die nicht vom Mittel- oder Sternpunkt ausgehen (d.h. kein Neutral- oder Mittelleiter). Sie verbinden die Stromquelle (Generator) mit den Stromverbrauchern.

Deine Vermutung ging also in die richtige Richtung.

Comment: entschuldige mal, das ist doch keine hinreichende Quelle und die Schlussfolgerung ist auch nicht gerechtfertift. Hier sieht man wieder schön wie "Sprachforscher" nach dem Ausschlussprinzip arbeiten: Eine Alternative ist mangels Sachkenntnis nicht ersichtlich, "also" locker aus der Hüfte schießen, die erste Vermutung ist ja oft die richtige.

Answer (score 0):

[image: drei Außenleiter und in der Mitte der Neutralleiter]

Das Bild zeigt die drei Außenleiter L1, L2 und L3 und in der Mitte den Neutral- oder Null-Leiter. Man stelle sich einen Magneten vor, der senkrecht zu seiner Pol-Achse rotiert. Außen, im Winkel von je 120°, sind drei Spulen angebracht (im Bild als weiße Rechtecke dargestellt), in denen vom rotierenden Magneten Strom induziert wird. Die inneren Enden der Spulen werden zum Neutralleiter zusammengeschaltet, die drei äußeren Enden sind die drei Außenleiter.

In einem Drehstrommotor werden die Spulen auf dieselbe Weise geschalten. Die drei Spulen erzeugen ein rotierendes Magnetfeld, das genau gleich schnell rotiert wie der Magnet im Generator, und diesem rotierenden Magnetfeld versucht der Rotor des Motors zu folgen, und dadurch entsteht die Drehbewegung.

Die fünfte Leitung in einem Drehstromkabel ist die Erdung.

In einem Drehstromkabel ist die Erdung die Leitung mit einer gelb und grün gestreiften Isolierung, die Isolierung des Nulleiters ist hellblau und die drei Außenleiter haben die Farben braun (L1), schwarz (L2) und grau (L3). Das ist EU-weit so genormt und gilt seit 2005. Davor gab es auch weiße und rote Isolierungen für Außenleiter.

Comment: "Meine Idee wäre, dass es so ist, weil der Nullleiter in einer Stern- und Dreiecksschaltung in der Mitte ist und die anderen Leiter halt außen sind." Heißt das, dass er damit recht hat?

Comment: @choXer ja, genau das Schaltbild hatte ich im Kopf.

Comment: Ich geb zwar kein -1, aber weiß auch nicht, ob hier die Frage wirklich beantwortet wurde.

Comment: @choXer: Ich weiß nicht, ob Torge recht hatte oder nicht, weil er in seiner Frage offen lässt, worauf sich »außen« bezieht. Wenn er den Generator meint, hat er recht. Wenn der das Kabel meint, hat er nicht recht. Im Kabel sind meist alle 5 Leitungen in irgend einer Position angeordnet. Im Kabel gibt es keine inneren oder äußeren Leitungen. Ich habe mich entschieden die Frage dadurch zu beantworten, dass ich die Herkunft des Namens beschreibe. Außerdem sprach Torge von nur ein einem Leiter, während es in Wahrheit 3 sind.

Comment: Das ist zwar eine sehr gute Beschreibung, erklärt aber nicht den *Grund* für die Bezeichnung "Außenleiter". Und noch etwas Interessantes fiel mir bei der Antwort auf, das aber nichts mit diesem Sachverhalt zu tun hat. Das Wort "geschalten" (statt "geschaltet") habe ich bisher nur von Sprechern aus den östlichen Regionen Deutschlands gehört. Falls es hier kein Tippfehler ist, scheint es auch in Österreich verwendet zu werden. Wäre vielleicht eine Frage in diesem Forum wert, in welchen Sprachregionen es benutzt wird.

Comment: @PaulFrost: Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Österreichisches_Deutsch#Partizip_Perfekt:_-et_und_-en

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke, sehr interessant!